# How can I use these "closed" power outlets?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I just bought a new home. It seems that the builder had some outlets open (where I can plug any devices), while some are closed (I can't plug anything). Is there a device I can rent or buy from any hardware store that would allow me to pop the closed outlets open SAFELY? Also, some of the outlets says "protected surge" on them.

Comment: Most likely they have child-proof outlet covers which can be removed with a straight screwdriver. Also a picture would be helpful in identifying what you have on those outlets.

Comment: Or they may be tamper proof outlets which have built in safety covers.  They often require a little more force than usual to insert the plug.

Comment: Whats your location? Posting a picture would be helpful. Like @Grant said tamper proof receptacles are required by the 2008 National Electric Code(US) in a new and renovated residential buildings. Sometimes you have to just wiggle the plug side to side to get the plastic shield inside the receptacle to slide out of the way.

Comment: The TR outlets don't require "more force" (they might...) so much as they require that you push the plug in absolutely straight so that you put pressure on the plastic guard, inside the outlet, on both sides at the same time. And wiggling the plug around a little as you're pushing doesn't hurt. But if you're not pressing both sides pretty equally, they're *designed* not to let you get the plug in.

Comment: Good info......problem solved...... thanks a lot.. Ron.

Answer (score 9):

The receptacles that say "protected surge" are either surge protection receptacles, or are protected by a surge suppression device in the panel.

As for the "closed" receptacles, those are most likely tamper resistant receptacles.   The guards should move out if the way when you plug things in. The guards only move when they are both pushed simultaneously, so make sure you're inserting the plug straight. If one blade touches first, the guards may not move. Also, the first time things are plugged into these receptacles, the guards seem to be a bit stiff. Wiggle the plug, and try a bit more force. After the receptacle has been used once or twice, it will be easier to plug things in.

Comment: Those TR receptacle drive me nuts, honestly. But they certainly do alleviate the fear of a young one sticking a fork in an outlet.

Comment: @Craig - I have been installing the Cooper tamper resistant outlets for about 3-4 years as my "lowest" grade and often will swap out an entire house (I usually buy older homes).  They are a little more expensive but do offer safety from children sticking things in and they are made better for sure.

Comment: We have these safety outlets in our 2-year-old kitchen, with plastic blades that are pushed out of the way when you plug a cord in. Some of them are incredibly difficult to use; I have to bear down on them with the plug, wiggling back and forth, to get those blades to move. A serious pain in the wazoo.

Comment: @DanielGriscom If it's that difficult to insert a plug, the receptacle may be broken or defective. You should try replacing it.